# ¿Cómo desactivar el subrayado azul en determinadas frases del editor VS Code?

Tags: r, vscode, extensiones

Estoy usando la extensión R de Yuki Ueda y me aparecen algunas frases subrayadas de azul que me alertan de ciertas caracteristicas del codigo.

Por ejemplo:

[image: Warning R extensión R de Yuki Ueda]

[image: Warning R extensión R de Yuki Ueda]

[image: Warning R extensión R de Yuki Ueda]

¿Cómo puedo desactivar la visualización de estos warnings en Visual Studio Code?

Comment: De todas maneras las sugerencias que te da no son malas, ¿por qué no quieres seguir los consejos?

Comment: Son bastante molestas visualmente, además, pueden hacerte pensar que tienes errores en el código cuando simplemente se tratan de sugerencias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ve a tus configuraciones personales usando `Ctrl+Shift+P` y seleccionando la opción `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` en español debe decir algo como `Preferencias: Abrir Configuración (JSON)`

En ese archivo te vas al final antes del cierre de llaves } pones una , en la línea de arriba y agregas

```
"r.lsp.diagnostics": false
```

Por ejemplo, si tu archivo termina así:

```
    ...otras configuraciones 
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
}
```

Quedará así:

```
    ...otras configuraciones 
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active",
    "r.lsp.diagnostics": false
}
```

Guardas, y quizás necesites reiniciar VSCode. Para volver a activar el linting tendrás que cambiar esa preferencia por `true`.

Comment: Por lo que veo, con esta sentencia eliminas todas las sugerencias, ¿no existe una clausula especfica para visualizar únicamente los errores?

Comment: Vas a tener que revisar manualmente la lista de linters disponibles https://github.com/r-lib/lintr#available-linters y jugar con el archivo .lintr para activar o desactivar los que necesites.

Comment: Cada necesidad es única, pero ¿cuál es el problema de usar comillas dobles en lugar de simples, usar snake_case y evitar las líneas largas? Desactivar un linter o montar una configuración especial por esas sugerencias (buenas en el caso de R) es un esfuerzo casi innecesario.

Comment: Tienes razón, es más complicado configurar el programa que seguir las pautas recomendadas

Answer (score 0):

comprueba si por casualidad tienes una extension llamada "code spell checker" que yo la tenia y me daba problemas con los subrayados, fue quitarla y todos los subrayados se me quitaron todos.