# ¿Cómo oculto el subrayado?

Tags: vscode

Llevo tiempo usando vscode y esta genial pero, en realidad esta línea me fastidia, ¿Hay alguna forma de ocultarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, la línea es de la función o la que señala los pares de corchetes, paréntesis y llaves?

Comment: mira, te dejo el [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499426/c%C3%B3mo-desactivar-el-subrayado-azul-en-determinadas-frases-del-editor-vs-code) a otra pregunta similar a la tuya